# How to import CSV file in SQL server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, import, csv

I am trying to import a CSV file in SQL Server 2008. `BULK INSERT` is a way to go but it is applicable for CSV from [SQL Server 2014 onwards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#interoperability).

What would be an alternative way to achieve this goal?

Any thoughts/ideas much appreciated.

Comment: Actually `FORMAT='CSV'` is 2017+ (14 is the major version number).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SQL Server has always supported bulk inserting from CSV files, you just have to specify field/row terminators.

file.csv contains:

```
foo,bar,1
blat,splunge,2
```

Then we do this:

```
CREATE TABLE #foo(a varchar(32), b varchar(32), c int);

BULK INSERT #foo FROM 'c:\temp\file.csv'
WITH (ROWTERMINATOR = '\n', FIELDTERMINATOR = ',');

SELECT * FROM #foo;
```

Results:

```
a        b        c
-------- -------- ----
foo      bar      1
blat     splunge  2
```

Answer (score 2):

Following link

https://support.discountasp.net/kb/a1179/how-to-import-a-csv-file-into-a-database-using-sql-server-management-studio.aspx

[image]

If you problem then next link follow
I hope solve your problem

https://host4asp.net/import-csv-file-using-sql-server-management-studio/